# Creating a generator function that lists the sum of all previous integers

Tags: python, generator

Sum of the integers:
keep adding the next integer
0 + 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 + ...
so the sequence is:
0, 1, 3, 6, 10, 15 .....

I am having trouble with this generator problem. What would be the best implementation of this?

Comment: Hi Mathew, show some code and tell us what is going wrong so that we can help you. Asking others to solve a problem is not well seem in S.O. in general

Comment: We're not going to do your homework for you. Please take the [tour] and read [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822/4518341) as well as [ask] more generally.

Comment: BTW, if it helps, these are called the [triangular numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_number).

Answer (score 3):

[`itertools.accumulate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.accumulate) does this for you:

```
from itertools import accumulate

for i in accumulate(range(6)):
    print(i)
```

---

```
0
1
3
6
10
15
```

Answer (score 2):

This is how I would go about implementing such a generator:

```py
def integer_running_sum(n):
    running_total = 0
    for integer in range(n):
        running_total += integer
        yield running_total

for total in integer_running_sum(6):
    print(total)

# 0
# 1
# 3
# 6
# 10
# 15
```